Magento 2 Map APIs Issue
I have deleted Array.from=$A from the legacy-build.min.js, google maps work Agien but other issue is dived, how can I solve this issue? can any one help please?


why u deleted Array.from=$A any reason?

I have Array.from=$A from legacy_build_main.js file so that google maps will function again.

I have Array.from=$A from legacy_build_main.js file so that google maps will function again.  Caus i had have this error
"The site overrides  Array.from() with an implementation that doesn't support iterables, Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to not work correctly"

I've faced with the same issue in Magento 2.4.2
As a temporary solution, I had to replace legacy-build.min.js (included as "prototype" in module-theme require-config.js) with empty JS using require.js file in custom module:
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'prototype': 'Vendor_Name/js/empty'
        }
    }
};

Empty JS looks like:
define([], function ($) {});

I know that it's a dirty solution, but it works. I went through all the pages in Magento frontend and didn't face with the errors.

Can you please use this instead of removing, do let me know if it helps.
Array.from=$A;
To:
Array.from=Array.from||$A;

i have did it google map work fine but the console  eeror stile there

@AhmedYahya can you share the console error

it same at the question https://i.sstatic.net/2fqvVb4M.png
